# How to catch an exception and respond with a status code in .NET Core

Tags: c#, .net, dependency-injection, exception, .net-core

I am running a .Net Core Web API project.
I have a startup file (below).  In the `Startup.ConfigureServices(...)` method, I add a factory method that creates an instance of IFoo.  I want to catch any exceptions that the IFooFactory throws and return a better error message with a status code.  At the moment I getting a 500 Error with the exception Message.  Can anyone help?

[image: 500 Error Message]

```
public interface IFooFactory
{
    IFoo Create();  
}

public class FooFactory : IFooFactory
{
    IFoo Create()
    {
        throw new Exception("Catch Me!");
    }
}

public class Startup
{
    public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
    {
        services.AddScoped<IFooFactory,FooFactory>();
        services.AddScoped(serviceProvider => {
            IFooFactory fooFactory = serviceProvider.GetService<IFooFactory>();
            return fooFactory.Create(); // <== Throws Exception
        });
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So I've posted two different answers as I read the question in two different ways - lots of deleting/undeleting/editing - not sure which one actually answers your question:

**To figure out what is going wrong when the app starts and doesn't work at all try this:**

Use the developer exception page in `Startup`:

```
public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IHostingEnvironment env,
                           ILoggerFactory loggerFactory)
{
    app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();
}
```

And in the `Program` class:

```
public static void Main(string[] args)
{
    var host = new WebHostBuilder()
        .UseKestrel()
        .UseContentRoot(Directory.GetCurrentDirectory())
        .UseIISIntegration()
        .UseStartup<Startup>()
        .UseApplicationInsights()
        .CaptureStartupErrors(true) // useful for debugging
        .UseSetting("detailedErrors", "true") // what it says on the tin
        .Build();

    host.Run();
}
```

**If you want to handle an occasional exception when the api is generally working then you can use some middleware:**

```
public class ExceptionsMiddleware
{
    private readonly RequestDelegate _next;

    /// <summary>
    /// Handles exceptions
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="next">The next piece of middleware after this one</param>
    public ExceptionsMiddleware(RequestDelegate next)
    {
        _next = next;
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// The method to run in the piepline
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="context">The current context</param>
    /// <returns>As task which is running the action</returns>
    public async Task Invoke(HttpContext context)
    {
        try
        {
            await _next.Invoke(context);
        }
        catch(Exception ex)
        {
            // Apply some logic based on the exception
            // Maybe log it as well - you can use DI in
            // the constructor to inject a logging service

            context.Response.StatusCode = //Your choice of code
            await context.Response.WriteAsync("Your message");
        }
    }
}
```

*There is one 'gotcha' with this - You can't write the status code if the response header has already been sent.*

You configure the middleware in the `Startup` class using the `Configure` method:

```
public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IHostingEnvironment env,
                           ILoggerFactory loggerFactory)
{
    app.UseMiddleware<ExceptionsMiddleware>();
}
```

Comment: Its two years since this post but this sample is many times linked. I have a question about using this with Authorize:

    [Authorize(Roles = Role.Admin)]
    public class UsersController : ControllerBase
    {}

This error is never handled in the middleware, when the user is not authorized. Is there a specific reason for that?

Comment: The order of middleware is very important. You have probably registered your auth middleware before your exception handling middleware.